# Finding the MLE of the mean on a non-normal distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

Given a non-normal distribution (a table) and a specific sample, how do I find the $MLE$ of the mean using the given sample?

To be more specific I was given the following distribution:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Number of Weeks} & 1       & 2       & 3         \\ \hline
Prob.           & 2\theta & 3\theta & 1-5\theta \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And the sample says that for 5 different people the results were: $1,2,3,2,3$ weeks. I know that $\bar{x} = \frac{11}{5}$ and that $E(x) = 1\cdot2\theta + 2\cdot3\theta + 3\cdot(1-5\theta) = 8\theta -15\theta +3 = -7\theta + 3$. I also know that $E(\bar{x}) = E(x)$.

What I don't know is how do I estimate the MLE using the above information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Given this data, the likelihood is $$\mathcal{L}(\theta |x) \propto Pr(X|\theta) = (2\theta)^1 (3\theta)^2 (1-5\theta)^2 $$

Now find the $\theta$ which maximises this, with the constraint that $2\theta$, $3\theta$ and $(1-5\theta)$ must be all be non-negative as they are probabilities.

Comment: Isn't this the likelihood of $\Theta$?

Comment: @Quaker In your question, you calculate the mean in terms of $\theta$. And MLE's have a property called [*functional invariance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Functional_invariance).

Comment: @shujaa I was asked to find the MLE of $\Theta$ in one of the former tasks, in this one I was asked to find the MLE of the mean not the parameter. There is a possibility that the question is not written properly and I would love to know if this is the case.

Comment: @Quaker The mean is $\phi(\theta)$ for a function $\phi$ given by yourself in your question. That's why shujaa points out the functional invariance property.

Comment: (+1: very clear).  Quaker, another option to consider--to help with the insight--is to rewrite the likelihood directly in terms of the mean, which you note equals $3-7\theta$. What the others are saying is, it doesn't matter whether you obtain the MLE for $\theta$ or for the mean, because the MLE of the mean must equal $3$ minus $7$ times the MLE of $\theta$.  (Such nice relationships among estimators do not hold for most other estimation procedures.)

Comment: @whuber, so if I was asked to find an MLE for $\theta$ and then asked to find an MLE for the mean, I am asked indirectly the same question? They might want to see if the students understand that they are identical.

Comment: Yes. Part of this is obvious and part is subtle. The obvious thing is that whatever value of $\theta$ maximizes the likelihood will correspond to the value of $3-7\theta$ that maximizes the likelihood, because the function $\theta\to 3-7\theta$ is one-to-one. You're not changing the likelihood; you're just changing how you express the parameter on which it depends--kind of like converting between pounds and kilos. The subtle parts in real applications are (1) you better check that the correspondence really *is* one-to-one and (2) confidence intervals may change in more complicated ways.

Comment: If my calculations are correct $\hat{\theta} = 0.12$ and $\hat{\mu} = 2.16$ If anyone did the calculations, can you please confirm ?

Comment: Quaker - that looks right to me.